# string editing: remove text and special char for data which is different in each cell

Tags: string, excel, editing

Data example:  FMNLA PROCESSED 29 OCT 14 55021549616216*****2934

This is contract coding and is different for each contract.  I need to remove the text, if any, including the date.  This information is always at the beginning, if it is coded.  I also need to remove the * and insert a comma after each 2 numbers, but I should be able to do that.  Basically any text before a space should be deleted, but it would have to run more than once to delete each section of the date text.

This data is imported from Excel.  I can't get Excel formulas to work there.  If I do Ctrl H to look for the *, the find text goes to cells which don't have the *.  I tried to change the format from general to text, but it didn't work.  And, I don't know any way to get rid of the variable text/date information since it also included numeric, so I decided to see what could be done in Access.  I do lots of basic stuff in Access, but no code.  There are about 400 contracts so editing is too time consuming.

The result I am expecting for the sample is: 55,02,15,49,61,62,16,29,34

I hope I have enough background for an assist!

Answer (score 0):

Please try (in Excel) Find what: `*` (asterisk space), Replace All, followed by:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*****",",")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the last "chunk" of data:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",255)),255)),"*","")
```

To insert a comma every second char will need a UDF, this will do it:

```
Function AddCommas(MyText As String) As String
Dim X As Long, TempText As String
If Len(MyText) < 3 Then
    InsertComma = MyText
Else
    TempText = Left(MyText, 2)
    For X = 3 To Len(MyText) Step 2
        TempText = TempText & "," & Mid(MyText, X, 2)
    Next X
    AddCommas = TempText
End If
End Function
```

Then you would wrap the original formula like so:

```
=AddCommas(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",255)),255)),"*",""))
```